# Arithmetic Series: find the sum of 25 terms given 2 terms and their values

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, summation, arithmetic-progressions

I need help with this question:

"Find *S<sub>25</sub>*, given an arithmetic series whose 8th term is 16 and whose 13th term is 81."

What I did was:

**1. Found the common difference (*d*) like this:**

81 - 16 = 65 
13 - 8 = 5 
65 ÷ 5 = **13** *(common difference)*

**2.Found the 1st term like this:**

16 - 8 x 13 = -88 *(T<sub>1</sub>)*

**3. Substituted it into the formula *S<sub>n</sub> = n/2(2a + d(n - 1))*, where *n* = 25, 
 *a* = *T<sub>1</sub>* = -88, and *d* = 13:**

S<sub>25</sub> = 25/2 ( 2(-88) + 13(25-1)) = 1700 (the sum of 25 terms)

But the answer to this question in my book is S<sub>25</sub> = 2025

Please explain me where  is my mistake or what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The first term is $16 - \color{red}7 \times 13 = -75$. Follow it up, and you will get the right answer.

Comment: This is a fencepost error (look it up on Wikipedia).  The eighth term is only seven differences from the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d=\frac{a_n-a_m}{n-m}$$ for all $n\neq m$.

Thus, $$d=\frac{16-81}{8-13}$$ or
$$d=13.$$
Now, $$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d,$$ which gives
$$16=a_1+7\cdot13$$ or
$$a_1=-75.$$
Here is your mistake.